# asp.net mvc custom ViewPage, textboxfor throwing exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, custom-view

I have custom View page like given below.

```
public  abstract class CustomViewPage : WebViewPage
{

}

public abstract  class CustomViewPage<T> : CustomViewPage where T : class
{

}
```

here is my customer class

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Now on my index.cshtml

```
@model SomeNameSpace.Customer
```

@{
       ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
   }

### @ViewBag.Message

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)

I have changed the web.config to use my custome customviewpage by this setting

When the navigate to home page it throws an exception

CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Title' and no extension method 'Title' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

```
public abstract  class CustomViewPage<T> : ViewPage<T> where T : class
{

}
```